# Display json images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, image, localhost, getjson

I'm trying to display JSON array-data using jQuery. I'm using other examples that I found on internet but I keep getting errors and problems.

When I try confirm(val.image); I get a pop-up: "unidentified".

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON( "images.json", function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                confirm(val.image);
        });    
    });

});
```

images.json

```
{
    "images": [
        {
             "name": "Image 1",
             "image": "images/image1.jpg"
        },
        {
             "name": "Image 2",
             "image": "images/image2.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

(I'm using wamp/localhost).

Comment: You can't load JSON from your filesystem using Javascript, IIRC. You need to serve the file to your JS script through localhost.

Comment: Should $.getJSON( "C:/wamp/www/file/images.json", function( data ) {... work?

Comment: Are you really using `(wamp/localhost)`? .... If so, could you be using `<base href="file:///C:/wamp/www/file/" />` in the head of your page?

Comment: Nope. Serve images.json from localhost

Comment: Ok thanks, it worked. But now if I use: confirm(val.image); I get a pop-up with "unidentified".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are able to get the JSON properly

You should use data.images instead of data (data is an object where data.images is the array to loop through)

```
$.each(data.images, function(index, value) {
    alert(value.image);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/361wr7Lg/

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting the console-error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $.each( data.images, function( i, val ) {
            alert(val.image);
            alert(val.name);
    });
```